# Why are the the Wifi options for my Canon EOS not showing?

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, wifi

In the menu/settings, `Wi-Fi/NFC` → `Disable` and `Wi-Fi Function` are greyed out, not white like the others, and I can't select them. What do I do?

Comment: Mention your model in the question.

Comment: What other settings are you using when this occurs?

Comment: Have the same problem with my Canon 5D3. Can't find why Wifi function is not under format card. I can see it in MY MENU as grey. Tried everything. Have a W-E1 - what should I try?

Comment: @Titi did you read the answer below?

Comment: Without telling us what particular model you are using there is no "correct" answer. It depends on whether your camera has built-in wi-fi or depends on an external wi-fi unit such as the WFT-E7A Wireless File Transmitter or the W-E1 Wi-Fi Adapter.

Comment: I appreciate all your help. It's sorted now and I used the answer below to do so. At the time I didn't know what model I had; hence the vagueness. Thank you.

Comment: @Forestfluffstuff The purpose of the SE network is to help *everyone else* who may also have a similar question as yours without requiring them to ask the same question again. It's not just about the fact that you have solved your problem, it is also about helping others solve similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Canon EOS series disables Wifi if you enable HDR, or certain other functions (there seems to be no logic behind it).

Check your manual for your specific model; Don't rely on common sense, as the limitations are arbitrary and illogical.

Comment: Thank you!! This really helped and it's sorted now! Much appreciated!!!