# Wi-Fi settings for W-E1

Tags: canon-5d-mark-iii, wifi-sd

Basically when I got in the menu/settings "Wi-Fi/NFC Disable" and "Wi-Fi Function" are in grey, not white like the others, and I can't select them. What do I do?

I have this problem with my Canon 5D3. I can't find why Wifi function is not under format card. I can see it in MY MENU as grey. I've tried everything. I have a W-E1 - what should I try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Wifi option on my Canon EOS isn't showing?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/85841/the-wifi-option-on-my-canon-eos-isnt-showing)

Comment: @mattdm the other question seems to be about built-in wi-fi on several EOS models. This question is about using the W-E1 card that fits in the SD card slot on a limited number of specific EOS camera that do not offer built-in wi-fi.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a W-E1 - what should I try?

You should try an WFT-E7A Wireless File Transmitter with your Canon EOS 5D Mark III. It is the only wireless solution sold by Canon that is compatible with your camera.

The Canon Wi-Fi Adapter W-E1 is currently (as of April 17, 2017) [compatible](https://shop.usa.canon.com/shop/en/catalog/wifi-adapter-w-e1) with only three cameras:

- EOS 7D Mark II
- EOS 5Ds
- EOS 5Ds R

Your EOS 5D Mark III is not compatible with the W-E1, nor is any other Canon EOS camera not listed above. Canon *might* provide firmware updates for specific camera body models in the future that could make them compatible *if* the hardware design doesn't preclude a good signal from the SD card location.

Answer (score 0):

In the manual there is a sektion on page 344. Using Ey-Fi cards.
https://www.bhphotovideo.com/lit_files/42005.pdf
Many tutorials on youtube ther is explained how it works.
Have they taken the posibilyties away.

Comment: The question is about W-E1

Comment: And the W-E1 is not an Eye-Fi card. Note that Canon does not guarantee compatibility with any Eye-Fi card and refers users to the card's manufacturer for any issues that may arise trying to use an Eye-Fi card in the EOS 5D Mark III (or any other EOS camera).